# Angular - dynamic component generation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to get an architectural question answered and doing so through the context of using a modal as an example. So for starters, please don't answer this question with "use bootstrap's modal service".

Basically, I want to know what the "Angular way" is around the case when one needs html to appear out of thin air, and apply components or directives to it. A data request error modal is a good example: if for instance, a component tries to load some kind of data, and the data comes back with some kind of error, I want the data service to be able to trigger a modal programmatically.

This begs the question: where does the template go, in this case? Unless I'm mistaken, a directive won't be compiled for markup that isn't on the page, which from an architectural standpoint is desirable (e.g. I don't want code on the page that is unlikely to be used, like in the case of an error modal which isn't terribly common). A service would have to be attached to a controller, which, same case, won't be added unless I have the markup on the page.

What is the pattern, then, for activating a component that is essentially (and in my opinion, desirably so) non-existent when the page loads? I'd ideally prefer the modal component to be ignored entirely until the user experience requires it. So far, ng-if statements, via including a single div somewhere on the page, seem the best approach. But even that is technically "messy", since you're adding markup to the page that is supporting only a "potential" case.

It'd be nice to be able to, from some service or controller or directive, broadcast a "triggerErrorModal" event, pass it some arguments, and have the application spin up the modal component. Note, there are other cases where this could work, so think of this as a more general question.

Thoughts?

Comment: Use Bootstraps modal service ;] It does exactly what you want, and it does it well. If you need the details, look at the source code.

Comment: Did you not read the post? This is an architectural question explicitly saying not to give that exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have said that you don't want to just be sent to bootstrap's modal service.. However.. looking into the source code gives a lot of information about how to do this.

Basically you can add an HTML element using:

```
var el = angular.element('<div class="new-thing"><my-directive></my-directive></div>')
```

Add it to the page:

```
var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
body.append(el)
```

And then compile it by:

```
var compiled = $compile(el)($scope);
```

Comment: Okay, but where would you put this logic?

Comment: @dudewad Where you put it depends on what you're doing (could be used in a controller, or a service, or even a directive). You kept your question very vague so I intentionally gave a vague answer. I didn't want to assume anything. If you have a more specific example in mind I'd be happy to help.